# Port changes while sending file to FTP

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm working in C# and I try to send a file in a FTP. There is my code :

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{ 
    try
    {
        Uri address = new Uri($"ftp://{FTP_address}:{FTP_port}/{Path.GetFileName(file.FullName)}");
        byte[] rawResponse = client.UploadFile(address, "STOR", file.FullName);

        string response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rawResponse);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventLog.logException(null, ex);
    }
}
```

There is an exception. I defined FTP_address to 'XX.XX.XX.XX' and port to 'YYYYY'. In my logs, there is :

> System.Net Information: 0 : [8576] FtpControlStream#39451090 - Created connection from AA.AA.AA.AA:BBBBB to XX.XX.XX.XX:YYYYY.
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [8576] Associating FtpWebRequest#25342185 with
>   FtpControlStream#39451090
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [8576] FtpControlStream#39451090 - Received response [220-FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta 220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org) 220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/]
>
> [...]
>
> System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [8576] Socket#19515494::UpdateStatusAfterSocketError() - ConnectionRefused
>
> System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [8576] Exception in Socket#19515494::Connect - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it XX.XX.XX.XX:ZZZZZ.

The firewall on the FTP allows just port YYYYY. My request is defined to XX.XX.XX.XX:**YYYYY**, but on the error message, address is XX.XX.XX.XX:**ZZZZZ**. While port did have change ? And how can I be sure to request the good port ?

Comment: That's how FTP works. You have a command port, usually 21, and a data port which is opened per command that requires a data stream.

Comment: Is FTP running on server?  First try ftp in IE using ftp://XX.XX.XX.XX.  If should return with a gui to select folder.  It may ask for a user and password.   It also may switch to secure mode FTPS.  Passed on results you can then update your code.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm searching but I don't understand. The administrator of the FTP only opened port YYYYY and only authorize my IP and an IP in a server. When I run this piece of code in my computer, it's OK. When I run it on the server, there is an error.